# How do I give an unchecked checkbox value in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to make it so that an unchecked checkbox has value while a checked checkbox has none.

```
<form>
<input style="visibility:hidden" type="checkbox" name="box" value="a" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="b" checked />
</form>
```

Apparently at one point, this would have worked as the second check box supposedly overrode the value of the first. But now, it seems that both values are submitted.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: radio inputs are one-of-the-above, checkboxes are one-or-more-of-the-above...

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using a checkbox, change your code to:

```
<form>
  <input style="visibility:hidden" type="radio" name="box" value="a" checked />
  <input type="radio" name="box" value="b" checked />
</form>
```

The input type radio accepts only one option, while the checkbox takes more than one option per group, so since the user can't remove the checked from the top one, you get both sent server side.